# Adding Markdown into my Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, markdown

I am trying to add Markdown to my Rails 3 web app but am having problems.

I have tried rdiscount and markdownizer but either they're not working or I'm not writing the correct code for them.

The code I have at the moment to display a text field is `<%=h simple_format (@user.desktopinfo) %>`

I want to increase the functionality of this text by adding Markdown but I am unable to get it work, please help! :)

**EDIT 2**

Using markdownizer broke my app, so I am now using BlueCloth. Add `bluecloth` to the gem file and add this  `<%= raw BlueCloth.new(@user.desktopinfo).to_html %>`

:)

**EDIT**

Actually, just trying again...

With markdownizer, with `markdownize! :desktopinfo` in the user model and `<%= @user.rendered_desktopinfo %>` on the page that shows the text, I get this:  `<h1>this is a h1</h1>` on the text when I enter

```
this is a h1
============
```

so I am halfway there! How do I now turn this code into html?

Comment: Please include code samples or the errors that you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really specified exactly what you are after, but I use bluecloth when working with markdown.  You can add 'bluecloth' to your Gemfile.

To parse your markdown it is as simple as:

```
<%= raw BlueCloth.new(YOUR_MARKDOWN).to_html %>
```

You need the keyword raw. so the HTML is not escaped.

```
<%= raw @user.rendered_desktopinfo %>
```

Comment: You probably need "<%= raw @user.rendered_desktopinfo %>" the HTML is escaped by default in rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [rdiscount](https://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount) which substitutes for bluecloth but is faster and better maintained.

[Ryan Tomayko's comparison](http://tomayko.com/writings/ruby-markdown-libraries-real-cheap-for-you-two-for-price-of-one) is a good write up regarding the different libraries for using markdown in Ruby.